# Does FaceTime currently work on iOS 8.1.1?

Tags: iphone, ios, facetime

I have an iPhone 6 running iOS 8.1.1 and have been unable to make or receive FaceTime calls since early October. When I call it looks normal but my recipient never receives the call. When I am called, it looks to the caller as if my phone is ringing but it never does. Does anyone know if FaceTime still works on this version of iOS?

Comment: Well, I know it works on OS X Mavericks, which is a year older than iOS 8. (Mavericks was 2013–2014, iOS 8 was 2014–2015).